# Copy filtered data to another sheet but creates a blank row if it met a condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

For example, I have this data,

[image]

I want to filter the data which is "USA" and copy it to another sheet but I have to creates a blank row if it met a condition. For example like this

[image]

Is it possible?
I have also tried

```
IF(AND(F2=FALSE, NOT(ISBLANK(F2))), "", INDEX(QUERY('Sheet 1'!A2:E, "Select A where A contains '"&"USA"&"'"),COUNTIF($F$2:F2,TRUE),1))
```

But it didn't work as I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a formula version:

```
=ArrayFormula(
     array_constrain(
        sortn(
          filter(
              {if(A:A="USA",A:A,),if(A:A="USA",B:B,),A:A="USA",
               if(A:A="USA",row(A:A),iferror(vlookup(row(A:A),if(A:A="USA",row(A:A),),1,true),0)+1)},
          A:A<>""),
        1000,2,4,1),
     1000,3)
)
```

The reason for the long formula is mainly finding a way to get just one row to replace one or more rows that don't start with USA. The basis of the formula is to do a lookup for non-USA rows to get the row number of the most recent USA row. All of the non-USA rows in the same block then have the same row number and can be discarded (apart from the first) using Sortn.

[image]

I have added an extra non-USA row at the beginning to check that this edge case works and falls through to the Iferror clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided Google Apps Script as tag, I assume you are open to script answers? If so, then I'll provide this code below. Is this what you are looking for?

```
function copyUSA() {
  var sheetSrc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheetDst = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var rowSrc = sheetSrc.getLastRow();
  var values = sheetSrc.getRange("A2:A" + rowSrc).getValues().flat();
  
  values.forEach(function (value, index){
    var rowDst = sheetDst.getLastRow() + 1;
    if(value == "USA"){
      // If USA, copy then replace third column with TRUE
      var row = index + 2;
      sheetSrc.getRange(row + ":" + row).copyTo(sheetDst.getRange(rowDst + ":" + rowDst));
      sheetDst.getRange("C" + rowDst).setValue("TRUE");
    }
    else{
      // If not, set third column to FALSE
      sheetDst.getRange("C" + rowDst).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  });
}
```

**Sheet1:**

[image: sheet1]

**Sheet2:**

[image: sheet2]

My assumptions were based from your formula. These are:

1. I assumed that you add blank when it is not `USA`. Thus having 2 blanks on the output
2. If USA, 3rd column is TRUE, else, FALSE with blank data
3. Based on your formula, it seems your data starts at `A2`, thus I adjust the code too.
4. You are also getting the 4th and 5th column on your formula but since you didn't show it in your post, I can't assume any values for it.

If the answer isn't the one you are looking for, I apologize.